# Design question: How would you design a temporary user table?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, sqlite, django-models

I am in the process of designing a website that would allow sports coaches to create teams, and then add players to that team. The goal is to allow coaches to add players to their team and associate stats to them by entering match data.

The issue I'm running into is the ability for players to create their own account and link their account to one of the players the coach made. The coach would be able to enter a player account's unique ID and select a player he created on the team, and give the player access to the stats he entered for the 'fake' user. The fake user would be deleted at this point. My initial design for tackling this is as follows:

I will use the default 'Users' table, and link it to a 'Profile' table via a OneToOneField. Whenever a coach creates a player for their team, a user will be created and an associated profile. The fake user would have a UUIDField as an ID in the Profile table. I'm storing the stats for players as follows:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ... several stats as IntegerFields
```

The Stats table would take the fake user as an argument, and relate stats to that user. When a real user creates an account and the coach enter's their UUID and selects the fake user, the 'player' field in Stats would be replaced by the real user, and the fake user will be deleted.

My question is, is this the best way to approach this issue? It doesn't feel good to pollute the user table with users with no username or password (is that even allowed?), though if a separate table were made for fake users I believe there would be issues with the player field.

```
player = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The player field relates the stats table to the User table, and expects a User Object. If it instead related to a fake user entry, I wouldn't be able to assign it to a real player, as it isn't a fake user object.

I'm sure there is a name for this issue that I'm not aware of as it must be a common problem in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a temporary table(model) at all in this case.  Instead, I suggest you create a `Player` model that has the UUID field and a OneToOneField to `User`(null=True).  `Stats.player` should point to the `Player` model.  Then when a player registers with the site, simply assign request.user to player.user.

Since you have 2 types of users, players and coaches, it makes sense to have a different "profile" for players.  That player "profile" is the `Player` model.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution.